# What is the minimum number of coloured shirts each person needs to bring?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I have 13 people to select a single team of 4 from. Each team member will then be assigned one of four colours when the team is chosen. Yellow, Blue, Green, Orange. Once the team is selected, the remaining 11 people are not required.

In order to ensure that any possible combination of these 13 people into 1 team of 4 will each be able to wear a unique coloured shirt, I propose that each team member needs to bring along enough coloured shirts (from the 4 colours) so that in any given combination of the 13 people, they are all wearing only one of the four colours and all four colours are different.

I believe there are 715 different combinations of "teams" that can be formed from these 13 people, but I can't then calculate the next part. Of course each person *could* bring 4 shirts each, then it will work, but is it possible that the 13 people can bring less than four shirts each to fulfil these requirements? They can be told which coloured shirts to bring, so that person A can bring yellow and blue, and person B green and orange, for example.

Comment: Hint: can you make a team from the people who didn't bring a Yellow shirt?

Comment: It sounds like you are selecting three different teams with one person left over, then having all the members of a team wear the same color, which is different from the other teams.  Your question does not say that.  Please update.

Comment: I have reworded and updated the question slightly, hopefully it is clearer. I am only forming 1 single team of 4 people, from the 13 people available. Then when chosen, I want each of the 4 people to be able to wear a different shirt to the other 3 people.